# How to change size of circles in paintComponent?

Tags: java, paintcomponent, repaint

I have this paintComponent where I have to draw a circle of the size `int size` because it has to be altered by `setSmallCircle()` and `setBigCircle()`. But I'm very new to java and I have no clue how to do this

So far I have this:

```
public class ReactionPanel extends JPanel {

boolean setSmallCircle= false;
Color color = new Color (255,0,0); //color  = red
Color c = new Color (255,255,0); //color = yellow
int size;
int x = 250;
int y = x;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
  super.paintComponent(g);
  if (setSmallCircle == true){
    setSmallCircle(g);
  }
  else if(setSmallCircle==true){
    setBigCircle(g);
  }
}

void setSmallCircle(Graphics g, Color c){
  size = 50;
  g.setColor(c);
  g.drawOval(x,y,size,size);
  g.fillOval(x,y,size,size);
}

void setBigCircle(Graphics g, Color c){
  size = 150;
  g.setColor(c);
  g.drawOval(x,y,size,size);
  g.fillOval(x,y,size,size);
}
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be compiling. (error: `setBigCircle(java.awt.Graphics,java.awt.Color) in ReactionExperiment.ReactionPanel cannot be applied to (java.awt.Graphics)` ) 
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

oh and, I also have to call repaint. Do I do this before the closing brace for my class ReactionPanel or somewhere else?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which line causes that error?

Comment: line `setSmallCircle(g);` and `setBigCircle(g)` in the if-else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (setSmallCircle == true){
  setSmallCircle(g);
}
else if(setSmallCircle==true){ // Error
  setBigCircle(g);
}
```

Instead do in paintComponent:

```
if (setSmallCircle) {
    size = 50;
} else {
    size = 150;
}
g.setColor(c);
g.drawOval(x,y,size,size);
g.fillOval(x,y,size,size);
```

Instead of `someBoolean == true` one can use `someBoolean`, and
instead of `someBoolean != true` use not (`!`): `!someBoolean`.
Here an `else` was sufficient.

Comment: Thank you! This also makes my code look better and easier to read. Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `setSmallCircle()` as

```
void setSmallCircle(Graphics g, Color c)
```

This means that you need to pass it two parameters, a `Graphics` object and a `Color` object. However, you only call it with

```
setSmallCircle(g);
```

which only passes a `Graphics` object to the method.

Comment: Hm, okay yeah that seems logical. But how do I add the parameter `Color color` or `Color c` then? Because (like below) I can't put `Color.YELLOW` per requirements of my assignment.

Comment: @Laynie_x You have already declared some color variables. Use those. p.s. Perhaps `yellow` would be a better name than `c`. This would obviate the need for a comment to describe the variable.

Comment: I agree, but I'm required to use `color` and `c`. Do I do this then with `Color.c`? (When I do this it gives me another error)

Comment: `Color.c` tells the compiler to find a **static** variable named `c` in the `Color` class. Your `c` is neither `static` nor in the `Color` class. To access variables inside your own class, just use the variable name by itself.